# Как округлить края у Bitmap (Android)?

Tags: android, bitmap

**Как у Bitmap-изображения округлить края по необходимому радиусу?**

Сразу скажу, что библиотеки типа CircularImageView не нужны, потому что интересует конкретно изменение Bitmap, а не View.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18229358/bitmap-in-imageview-with-rounded-corners

Comment: http://evel.io/2013/07/21/rounded-avatars-in-android/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Спасибо комментаторам, ответ получен.

```
public static Bitmap getRoundedCornerBitmap(Bitmap bitmap, int radius) {
        Bitmap output = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap
                .getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas(output);

        final Paint paint = new Paint();
        final Rect rect = new Rect(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
        final RectF rectF = new RectF(rect);

        paint.setAntiAlias(true);
        canvas.drawARGB(0, 0, 0, 0);
        canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, radius, radius, paint);

        paint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_IN));
        canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, rect, rect, paint);

        return output;
    }
```